# Zephir curl dependency

Tags: curl, zephir

How to properly introduce the curl extension as a dependency?

Simply trying to create an array that references constants from the [curl extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) like so

```
public function __construct()
{
    let this->options = [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER : false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER : true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT : 30,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        : 30
    ];
}
```

causes compile time warnings / errors

> Warning: Constant 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' does not exist at compile
> time in /home/nathan/gitRepos/zephir/rcurl/rcurl/curl.zep on 89
> [nonexistent-constant]
>
> ```
>           CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT : "30",  -----------------------------------^
> ```
>
> Zephir\CompilerException: Invalid value type: string in
> /home/nathan/gitRepos/zephir/rcurl/rcurl/curl.zep on line 89
>
> ```
>           CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT : "30",  -----------------------------------------^
> ```

I started looking in the generated **config.json** file and found a `requires` section to which I added `curl` so it now looks like this

```
"requires": {
    "extensions": [
        "curl"
    ]   
},
```

However now the compiler errors have changed

> Zephir\Exception:     Could not load extension : curl,    You must add
> extensions above before build this extension

Comment: Weird, I installed the extension via `apt-get` and now it works even without the config.json revision. Strange that had any impact, considering the apt package is binary...